# How to open .txt file saved from main window to combo-Box of other-popup window with pyqt5?

Tags: python, user-interface, pyqt5

I have created the main window which saves a .txt file i.e text entered in label team name

[image]

Second Image shows another popup-main window which is invoked when evaluate menu bar is clicked

[image]

Comment: read [ask],  review [tour] and improve your question.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow.  Your best bet here is to do your research, [search](https://stackoverflow.com/help/searching) for related topics on SO, and give it a go. If you get stuck and can't get unstuck after doing more research and searching, post a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) example of your attempt and say specifically where you're stuck. People will be glad to help. Good luck!   Definitely read the links suggested by @eyllanesc .